# nginx, reverse proxy wss, spring boot

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, spring-websocket

Trying to setup reverse proxy with WS support, but I'm getting 403 (forbidden). I'm confused why it happen, because everything works as expected without proxy. My config is here:

```
server {

    root /var/www/html8080;

    server_name game.memoux.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/game.memoux.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/game.memoux.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

If I'm trying to reach it with https: https://game.memoux.com/ websocket not work.
But if I'm trying to reach it with http://game.memoux.com:8080 everything works propoerly. It means, something wrong with my config, and not with application behind the proxy.

nginx error log from 05-11-2023

```
2023/11/05 01:46:15 [crit] 705581#705581: *2917 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 167.172.240.54, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/05 02:14:22 [error] 705581#705581: *2937 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 36.99.136.129, server: memoux.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "memoux.com"
2023/11/05 02:14:36 [error] 705581#705581: *2975 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 146.70.192.180, server: memoux.com, request: "GET /_next/static/chunks/framework-2c79e2a64abdb08b.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: >
2023/11/05 04:13:33 [crit] 705581#705581: *3022 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 65.49.1.17, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/05 06:51:34 [crit] 705581#705581: *3087 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 212.102.40.218, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/05 07:10:27 [crit] 705581#705581: *3110 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 68.183.200.199, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/05 07:44:42 [crit] 705581#705581: *3136 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 104.131.184.235, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/05 07:47:26 [crit] 705581#705581: *3147 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 35.216.204.22, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/11/05 08:25:08 [error] 705581#705581: *3177 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 3.249.231.245, server: memoux.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "memoux.com"
2023/11/05 11:02:06 [crit] 705581#705581: *3217 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 87.236.176.112, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the nginx logs?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres question updated

Comment: The proxy configuration seems fine, so it looks like an issue with the TLS cert. Does it work without SSL? `listen 443` (without ssl)?

Comment: @EricFortis, I suppose yes, but it does not work, so, it means something wrong. I'm doing a game, which contain two parts - first is "rest api", which work properly over SSL and WS api, which not work over SSL. In same time, both of them work over non-encrypted connection (port 8080). Also I check just now, and I see that error "SSL_do_handshage() failed" does not appears in the moment when I'm trying to run websocket

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change your 'proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";'
I don't think "upgrade" is the correct value for Connection.

Add

```
map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
"~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
default keep-alive; 
}
```

to server or http block and then

```
proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

in your location block.

Comment: in localhost it shows "upgrade" (see attached screenshot). Will try your solution, but it did not looks right.

Answer (score 0):

It was application-server misconfiguration.
It complain for CORS policies. Spring security CORS config is not related to websocket config (at least for me). I was able to find it only after I turn logs into debug mode, otherwise that error message was not shown by framework.